# The Logic of Null Values in Android Programming: Confused

Tags: android, null, nullpointerexception

I hope this is a very simple question, what is the Android equivalent to doing this in PHP:

PHP:

function BlahBlah ($first_var,$second_var,$optional_var_1=null,$optional_var_2=null) {

}

In Android it appears everything I feed into a function must have a non-null value for all variables. While I can add logic such as if statements to check for null values, why can't I simply pass through null values and have them be ignored?

My problem revolves around a function which enters a book into my sql database for my app. If I enter all of the book's information such as author, title, copyright, ISBN, etc. there is no problem as I am not supplying any null values. If however, I were to leave the copyright or ISBN as Null and try to pass these through to the function I get a nullpointerexception. Sometimes I don't need to record the ISBN or the copyright (this is an example and not the real app) so instead of making multiple functions such as addBook(...) addBookWithNoISBN(...) addBookWithNoCopyright(...) ... what is the better way to do this?

I believe I should be sending all of my variables to the function as a string array and perhaps do some processing in the function itself? Is there a better way?

I hope people get what I'm trying to say, thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you really want to be using empty strings rather than nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java supports something called method overloading, which lets you define multiple methods having the same exact name, but with different numbers/types of parameters:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

So you would end up coding a separate method for each possible combination.  They would then pass in null values where needed, and call the main method that does the core logic:

```
boolean test(int param1, String param2) {
    return test(param1, param2, null, null);
}
boolean test(int param1, String param2, String param3) {
    return test(param1, param2, param3, null);
}
boolean test(int param1, String param2) {
    // Do your logic here
    if(param1 == 'foo' && param3 == null)
        return false;
    if(param2 == param3)
        return true;
}
```

With this, it doesn't matter if you pass in 2, 3, or 4 variables as the same function is ultimately called with 'null' values for things you didn't pass.

Here's another example, where you have a single method name that can accept all sorts of input types:

```
boolean AddBook(int isbn)
{
    Book result = FindBookByISBN(isbn);
    return AddBook(result);
}
boolean AddBook(String asin)
{
    Book result = FindBookByAmazonId(asin);
    return AddBook(result);
}
boolean AddBook(String title, String author)
{
    Book result = FindBookByTitleAndAuthor(title, author);
    return AddBook(result);
}
boolean AddBook(Book theBook)
{
    if(theBook == null)
        return false;

    return MyBookCollection.Add(theBook);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be the route I want to take. I'd like to limit my logic statements within the methods and I believe this "recursive" approach is the way to do it. I must admit I do not fully understand the first example, but I will definitely read through your source, it is excellent and helping me get it.

Comment: Finished reading, not a long read and I highly recommend anyone who is coming from another programming language GO READ THIS!

Answer (score 1):

In android you can't  set the function paramaters to a default value. You have to pass the default value into the function or null and the check if the parameter is null in the function.

```
       function void test(int param1, String param2, String param3,..) {
               if(param2 == null) param2 = param2_Default_value; 
        }
```

Hope this explains it.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was thinking in the right ballpark at least!

Answer (score 1):

As long as in the function you don't do something that requires it to be not null, or check if its null with if(variable != null) first, it should not have a problem passing a null.

Comment: When building an xml document from database columns where nulls may be present I'll use something like          serializer.text(colvalue==null?"":colvalue);

Comment: Thank you, I must be doing something within the function (I guess these are more correctly called methods in Java?) that requires this value to be non-null, I will look.